# How to get a secondary div to always have the same height as the first div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs, called `signin` and `info`.
I want to make info to always have the same height as `signin` and if the text inside doesnt fit to make `info` have a scrollbar.

Is it possible to obtain this via some simple JS, html and css?
Here is what i have tried:

```
var firstDivHeight = document.getElementById('#signin').clientHeight;
document.getElementById("#info").style.height = firstDivHeight;
```

Here is a jsfiddle with all my html and css http://jsfiddle.net/sleshwave/4v7bvw5o/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `display:table`, in most cases, too, BUT because of your specific requests:

1) *info bar should have same height as form bar (not vice versa, #signin dictates info bar height)*

2) *info bar can have more content, and needs scrollbar, too*

i would use this:

```
window.onload = function(){
firstDivHeight= document.getElementById('signin').offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("info").style.height = firstDivHeight+'px';
}
```

In css:

```
#info {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
 overflow-y:auto;
    width:50%; //add desired width
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/29mzjq5x/3/

Notice: i've used offsetHeight, rather than clientHeight, because it will calculate paddings, and borders too...

Comment: Although i noticed a small problem. The two divs are set to have the same height whenever the page loads but if the window changes the info div will not be the same height as signin anymore

Comment: @StefanPricope, you have to add same calculation on resize: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize

Answer (score 0):

Change a little the structure and use the display:table/table-cell; properties.
http://jsfiddle.net/4v7bvw5o/3/

```css
@import http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto;
 #signin {
    display:table;
    border-spacing:1em;
}
form {
    background-color: red;
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    text-align: center;
    display:table-cell;
}
input[type=text], input[type=password], input[type=email] {
    width: 92%;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:8px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding-left:5px;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:Roboto;
    background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.3);
}
#info {
    background-color: red;
    display:table-cell;
}
input[type=submit] {
    width:92%;
    background-color:#1471BF;
    color:#fff;
    border:2px solid #1471BF;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-family: Roboto;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    -webkit-transition:border 0.3s, background-color 0.3s;
    transition:border 0.3s, background-color 0.3s;
}
input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #B93948;
    border:2px solid #B93948;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<title>New account</title>
<body style="background-color:#232324">
    
<h1 style="text-align:center">Creating a new account</h1>

    <div id="signin">
        <form>
            <br>
            <label>Username</label>
            <p></p>
            <input id="name" name="username" type="text">
            <p></p>
            <label>Email</label>
            <p></p>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email">
            <p></p>
            <label>Name</label>
            <p></p>
            <input id="nume" name="name" type="text">
            <p></p>
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <p></p>
            <input id="prenume" name="lastname" type="text">
            <p></p>
            <label>Password</label>
            <p></p>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="password">
            <p></p>
            <label>Confirm password</label>
            <p></p>
            <input id="repassword" name="password_conf" type="password">
            <p></p>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Register">
        </form>
        <div id="info">
            <p>This is the story about a guy named blue</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much,it somehow works.The only problem is that it doesnt have a scrollbar when text is added and it seems like signin is the same length as info,not the other way around. Still thanks a lot!

Comment: @StefanPricope maybe a screen of what you wanna will help :)

Answer (score 0):

[GCyrillus's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442099/gcyrillus) solution is better because it doesn't require `javascript`, you could also try a similar layout using `flexbox`.

If you want to use `javascript` however, this should work.

```
var firstDiv = document.getElementById('signin');
var secondDiv = document.getElementById('info');  

secondDiv.style.height = firstDiv.clientHeight + 'px';
```

Notice that this code should only run when the page is already loaded!

Answer (score 0):

I don't like to use table for layout.
You can use flex box layout, it has a good support in all major browsers.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Suggested solution:

Include both divs (.col) in other container (#container-div)and display it as flex

```
#container-div {
 Display: flex;
}
```

Use flex-grow property to grow the flex item to full width.

```
.col{
Flex: 1;
}
```

Don't forget to add vendor prefixes to support all browsers

Comment: I forgot to mention that i already tried using flexbox and it didnt appear to do anything. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Update about Scrolling:
To have the scrolling behaviour, you should specify a max-height to the column. Otherwise, flex items will grow as you add content and be always equal heights.
https://jsfiddle.net/EiyadZ/570L8yx5/6/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added it and it worked very nice